# django facebook attribute error using facebook_required decorator

Tags: django, facebook

I am getting an attribute error stating 
**Facebook instance has no attribute 'has_permissions'** 
when using facebook_required decorator.

My code snippet is:

```
@facebook_required
def update_status(request):
    import time
    quote = 'Hello World !!!' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    graph.put_wall_post(quote, profile_id=str(request.facebook.user.facebook_id))
    return HttpResponse('Status Updated !!!')
```

What is the problem here??

Comment: I think may be is something about  user token.

Comment: I am new to django facebook. Could you please tell me how I can get user token

Comment: can you say me what facebook lib are you using?

Comment: I am using django_facebook

Comment: http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/